# Extract ETL process of existing database

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl

I have a pretty complex database, I have both its source code and access to it. 
My job is to answer the question ‘from what file, given column is loaded?’. Currently what I do is just go through code, from target column to source file. I wonder if there is any tool that would make it automatic or generate it based on SQL?

I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: What tool are you use to load data? Some tools have such functionality, other don't.

Comment: Raw data is loaded into EXT tables using SSIS, then all operations and transformations are done within T-SQL queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server SSIS Data Lineage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49946154/sql-server-ssis-data-lineage)